# How to start Visual Studio solution using command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, command-prompt

I have a Integrated Services Solution saved as `itrs.sln`. However, I am unable to open it via command prompt.

Below is how I normally start Visual Studio:

```
runas /netonly /user:ABC "C:\devenv.exe"
```

Below is how I tried to open the solution from command prompt which did not work:

```
runas /netonly /user:ABC "C:\itrs.sln"
```

**Error says itrs.sln is not a valid Win32 application.**

Is there any way in which I can straight away open itrs.sln from command prompt ?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to send the password in to runas. At least, I've never been able to pipe one in

Comment: Any solution that you know of ? @billinkc

Comment: People had suggested things like AutoIt or HotKey or something like that but I never wanted to automate entering a password hard enough to explore that route. Even if it does work, whether it actually works under the context of an SSIS package executing seems dubious. What is the root problem you are trying to solve by launching an instance of Visual Studio from within the context of an SSIS package?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run Visual Studio with the `runas` command, then pass the solution file to it as an argument:

```
runas /netonly /user:ABC "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe C:\itrs.sln"
```

Comment: didnt work. it showed a bunch of RUNAS usage in command prompt

Comment: I have corrected my example above.  The difference is that the program name and the file to open in it must be in the same set of quotes rather than quoted differently ("program.exe option1.sln")